# Tree Traversal for getting the nodes in an Array

Tags: php, tree

I have a tree like this

```
      2 
   /  |  \
  3   4   6
     / \
    7   8
         \ 
          9
```

In db table look like this

```
    node_id parent_id  
       2        0
       3        2
       4        2
       6        2
       7        4
       8        4
       9        8
```

The problem is, If I pass 4 node id to a function, return should be in an array ( or comma separated ) with 7,8 and 9 ( means all nodes under 4 ). I have tried recursive function, but not getting what I really expected. Please suggest some possible way in PHP

Comment: What'v you tried? P.S. Welcome to Stack

Comment: I tried recursive function, but the problem is I didn't from what point I have to return the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ (originally it was published under mysql.com, but then deleted)

For your data you can try something similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `tree` (node_id INT NOT NULL,
parent_id   INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO `tree`(node_id, parent_id) VALUES(2,0),
(3,2),
(4,2),
(6,2),
(7,4),
(8,4),
(9,8);


SELECT t1.node_id AS lev1, t2.node_id AS lev2, t3.node_id AS lev3, t4.node_id AS lev4
FROM tree AS t1
LEFT JOIN tree AS t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.node_id
LEFT JOIN tree AS t3 ON t3.parent_id = t2.node_id
LEFT JOIN tree AS t4 ON t4.parent_id = t3.node_id
WHERE t1.node_id = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Answer won't results what I expected. There would be many nodes. Manual LEFT JOIN won't work.

Comment: so then you can scroll down the article I sent you and read about nested sets? Meaning you should change the way you store the tree to nested sets and then you end up in one basic query to retrieve sub-tree

Comment: I got another way to solve the issue. Using the same table, In PHP i have written function ( recursive ) which will push nodes to an array.